# Windows 8 Camera Facing

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-8, camera

Is there any way to check Camera facing in Visual studio? Not in app..using some api, may be through IMFMediaSource. I don't want to use it in an app, I just want to know whether camera is front or back facing..is there any function like  getCameraFacing() in android..IMFMediaSource pointer with me. Using it I want to call a function which will return to me the facing of Camera.Here is what I am trying:
int 
    CCameraDevice::init (IMFMediaSource* source, std::wstring name)
    {
    _source = source;
    _name   = name;

```
_source->AddRef ();
}
```

Just like AddRef is there any function or may be some other api?

Comment: I can't figure out what you mean by "not in app". Where would you call this API if not from an app?

Comment: Like some system call in Linux. I can not find any API which returns us the facing of camera from windows side like MFEnumDeviceSources to enumerate the count for device specified audio or video...See I usually work on Android..You just answer accordingly. I may not be asking it right but I guess you have understood

Comment: There might be a way to read the ACPI table and find an imaging device from there..but is there an easier way??

Comment: But you would make the system call from an app, right? Or are you writing a device driver?

Comment: No, not from application..Device driver..Yes...but no system call to check the facing of the camera..I can just know if there are two cameras (front and back) i.e just the count but can not know their respective facing

Comment: Now I'm confused. You say you're writing a device driver, but you can't use `IMFMediaSource` from a device driver. You also can't use `std::wstring` from a device driver. It's also not clear why a device driver is messing with cameras. Just make you device driver manage your device and let the application worry about choosing a camera.

Comment: yeah ok then, is there anything like IMFMediaSource which can help me choose the camera facing like the pointer mentioned here source it calls Addref() function.Something like that. Is there anyway API,system call any IMFMediaSource function just to know the camera facing (front or back)

Comment: for (UINT32 i = 0; i < count; i++)
 {
  WCHAR* name = NULL;
  
  hr = pp_devices [i]->GetAllocatedString (MF_DEVSOURCE_ATTRIBUTE_FRIENDLY_NAME,
              &name,
              NULL);
  if (FAILED (hr)) { continue; }

  // Skip ArcSoft Manager
  if(0 == wcsncmp (name, L"ArcSoft", 7)) { continue; }

  /* Try to activate the media source */
  IMFMediaSource* source = 0;
  hr = pp_devices [i]->ActivateObject (__uuidof(IMFMediaSource),
            (void**)&source);
  if (FAILED (hr)) { continue; }

  _num_cameras++;
 
  pp_devices [i]->Release ();
  SafeRelease (&source);
 }

Comment: In this for loop I need to insert an API which checks the camera facing corresponding to the camera found

Comment: That is not device driver code, so I'm still not sure what you mean by "in Visual Studio, not in app". In an app, you can inspect the [DeviceInformation.EnclosureLocation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.enumeration.deviceinformation.enclosurelocation.aspx).[Panel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.enumeration.panel.aspx) property.

Comment: By "Not in app" I meant I am not designing any Mobile app. Enclosure location just gives the location..See by what I see is that Windows does not allow us to check the facing of camera..It returns 0 for front and 1 for back camera by default..

Comment: Okay, "not in mobile app". You could've said that back at the beginning and saved a lot of questions.

Comment: yeah right..I am sorry..So do you know of any api??